# PySpark : Merge dataframes where one value(from 1st dataframe) is between two others(from 2nd dataframe)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to merge two dataframes on an identifier and condition where a date in one dataframe is between two dates in the other dataframe and groupby (calculate the sum) of the other column

Dataframe A has a date ("date"), number("number") and an ID ("id"):

```
| id    | date          | number | 

| 101   |  2018-12-01   | 250  |
| 101   |  2018-12-02   | 150  | 
| 102   |  2018-11-25   | 1000 | 
| 102   |  2018-10-26   | 2000 | 
| 102   |  2018-09-25   | 5000 | 
| 103   |  2018-10-26   | 200  | 
| 103   |  2018-10-27   | 2000 |
```

Dataframe B has Id("id"), fromdate("fromdate") and a todate("todate"):

```
| id    |    fromdate   | todate     | 

| 101   |  2018-10-01   | 2018-11-01 |
| 101   |  2018-11-02   | 2018-12-30 | 
| 102   |  2018-09-01   | 2018-09-30 | 
| 102   |  2018-10-01   | 2018-12-31 | 
| 103   |  2018-10-01   | 2018-10-30 | 
| 104   |  2018-10-01   | 2018-10-30 |
```

Now I need to merge these two dataframes on id and date and then sum all the numbers accordingly. 
For example:
Consider fourth row in dataframe B, For id 102, and in between those dates, we have two corresponding rows(Row #3,4) from dataframe Am Merge them by calculating the sum.

So the resulting row would be

```
| id    |    fromdate   | todate     | sum  |

| 102   |  2018-10-01   | 2018-12-31 | 3000 |
```

End result should be:
    | id    |    fromdate   | todate     | sum    |

```
| 101   |  2018-10-01   | 2018-11-01 | 0      |
| 101   |  2018-11-02   | 2018-12-30 | 400    |
| 102   |  2018-09-01   | 2018-09-30 | 5000   |
| 102   |  2018-10-01   | 2018-12-31 | 3000   |
| 103   |  2018-10-01   | 2018-10-30 | 2200   |
| 104   |  2018-10-01   | 2018-10-30 | 0      |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is detailed approach you can follow -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import * 

################
##Define Schema
################
schema1 = StructType([StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('date', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('number', IntegerType(), True)
                     ]
                    )


schema2 = StructType([StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('fromdate', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('todate', StringType(), True)
                     ]
                    )
################
##Prepare Data
################

data1  = [
(101,'2018-12-01',250 ),
(101,'2018-12-02',150 ), 
(102,'2018-11-25',1000), 
(102,'2018-10-26',2000), 
(102,'2018-09-25',5000), 
(103,'2018-10-26',200 ), 
(103,'2018-10-27',2000)
]

data2 = [
(101,'2018-10-01','2018-11-01'),
(101,'2018-11-02','2018-12-30'), 
(102,'2018-09-01','2018-09-30'), 
(102,'2018-10-01','2018-12-31'), 
(103,'2018-10-01','2018-10-30'), 
(104,'2018-10-01','2018-10-30')
]

################
##Create dataframe and type cast to date
################

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, schema1)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema2)

df1 = df1.select(df1.id,df1.date.cast("date"),df1.number)

df2 = df2.select(df2.id,df2.fromdate.cast("date"),df2.todate.cast("date"))
```

Define join condition and join dataframes

```
################
##Define Joining Condition
################

cond = [df1.id == df2.id, df1.date.between(df2.fromdate,df2.todate)]

################
##Join dataframes using joining condition "cond" and aggregation
################

from pyspark.sql.functions  import coalesce

df2.\
    join(df1, cond,'left').\
    select(df2.id,df1.number,df2.fromdate,df2.todate).\
    groupBy('id','fromdate','todate').\
    sum('number').fillna(0).\
    show()
```